# Using regex in javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

I cannot get to work the following example of Regex in JavaScript. Regex is valid, was tested on some webs testing Regex expression.

I want it to check if input is in format: `xxx,xxx,xxx`.
It is alerting wrong input all the time. Thanks for any help.

```
        var re = /[0-9a-zA-Z]+(,[0-9a-zA-Z]+)*/; 
        var toValidation = document.getElementsByName("txtSerial").value;
        alert(toValidation);
        if(!re.test(toValidation))
            return true;
        else
        {
            alert("Please insert valid text.");
            return false;
        }
```

Comment: Why the `!` in the `if` ? And you should use `/^ ... $/`.

Comment: I guess you have inverted the condition.

Comment: @anubhava the regex is incorrect too. It would match "123456".

Comment: Thanks dystroy ;) I didn't know about using  /^ ... $/ what is it for?

Comment: @user2775380 It matches both ends of the string.

Answer (score 2):

`document.getElementsByName("txtSerial")` will return all elements by that name (node collection). Node collections do not have an attribute named `value`, thus, .value will be `undefined` (as can be seen by your alert).

Depending on your markup, you will want to use

```
document.getElementById("txtSerial")
```

or

```
document.getElementsByName("txtSerial")[0]
```

(although the last one is certainly not ideal).